# How to Initialise an instance of GUITHREADINFO

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, coverity-prevent, coverity

I have declared the following

```
GUITHREADINFO gui;
```

The Coverity complains that gui is not initialised.

Can you please tell me how do I initialise it?

Best Regards

Chintan

Answer (score 1):

Well, you obviously need to populate the structure members with relevant data, but you can initialise it to zeros before doing so like this:

```
GUITHREADINFO gui = {0};
```

Before using it, refer to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632604%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to see what data should be set in each field. For exmaple:

```
gui.cbSize = sizeof(GUITHREADINFO);

// ... etc.
```

Comment: So just make it `GUITHREADINFO gui = { sizeof(GUITHREADINFO) };`